# I am using multiple buttons in javascript, how do I get a function to run when three of them are clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

I need a function to run when three buttons are clicked. This through javascript and ruby, connected through a .erb file in Ruby. For better specifics, I'm looking for something on the lines of a conditional statement, sort of like this:

```
if (c = true; d = true; e = true) {
alert("C Major")
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create the Variable clicks
2. Make a Function that runs onClick:

   ```
   function btnclick(){
      clicks = clicks + 1;
      if(clicks = 3){
        clicks = 0;
        myfunction();
      }
   }
   ```

myfunction is the function you want do do after 3 Clicks

So its counts the clicks and after 3 Clicks its resets the count and does your stuff.

UPDATE:
Instead of the Count Var use 3 different Vars for each Btn with a Boolean Value

```
 function btn1(){
           btn2 = TRUE
           if(btn1 And btn2 AND btn3){
             myfunction();
           }
        }
 function btn2(){
           btn2 = TRUE
           if(btn1 AND btn2 AND btn3){
             myfunction();
           }
        }
 function btn3(){
           btn3 = TRUE
           if(btn1 AND btn2 AND btn3){
             myfunction();
           }
        }
```

So that if every Butto got clicked once myfunction will be fired

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what I'm looking for is a function that runs when three individual and different buttons are clicked.